# Extracting text and HTML from the contents of an element using Web::Scraper

Tags: perl, web-scraping

Given the following HTML snippet:

```
<span itemprop="streetAddress">59 Court St.<br>City Hall</span>
```

I want to extract the contents of the `span` including the `<br>` tag. I can extract the text with the following:

```
 process 'span[itemprop="streetAddress"]', address => 'TEXT';
```

But this leaves out the `<br>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I cracked open the source code `Web::Scraper` and saw that you can set the value of the second argument to 'RAW' like so:

`process 'span[itemprop="streetAddress"]', address => 'RAW';`